# Multiprocessing to a function or for double for cycles. Python 3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to apply a multiprocessing logic for the following function or for the for cycles inside of the function, but I am new to the multiprocessing and I failed miserably :/

Additional info:
The json_file is loaded as a dic and his keys contains the full path to a file (many different locations) - /foo/bar/fofo/bar.h
The input_list contains path the a file from different level in the filesystem - fofo/bar.h

```
def matcher(json_file, input_list):
    with open(json_file) as jf:
        data = json.load(jf)
        key_list = data.keys()
        full_path_list = []
        for target in input_list:
            for key in key_list:
                if key.endswith("{}".format(target)):
                    full_path_list.append(key)

    return full_path_list
```

Can you guys help?
Thank you in advance!

Here are examples of the key_list and the input list:

key list:

```
['/foo/bar/123456/.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR.py', '/foo/bar/123456/.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR.pyc', '/foo/bar/123456/.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR.pye', '/foo/bar/123456/.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR_fight.h', '/foo/bar/123456/.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BARfoo.h', /bar/dir/98765/.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH.py', '/bar/dir/98765/.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH.pyc', '/bar/dir/98765/.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH.pye', '/bar/dir/98765/.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH_fight.h', '/bar/dir/98765/.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEHfoo.h]
```

input list:

```
['.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR.py', '.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR.pyc', '.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR.pye', '.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BAR_fight.h', '.BAR/fofo/baba/dir/BARfoo.h', .FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH.py', '.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH.pyc', '.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH.pye', '.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEH_fight.h', '.FOO/barbar/foofoo/rid/MEHfoo.h]
```

The length of both lists is 30000+.

Comment: For the additional info I meant:
The json_file* is loaded as a dic and his keys contains the full path to a file (many different locations) - /foo/bar/fofo/bar.h The input_list* contains path the a file from different level in the file system - fofo/bar.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you can share the dataset size and some example use case. Based on your current implementation, I'd say using a list comprehension along with `any` would help fasten the process.

```
full_path_list = [key for key in data.keys() if any(target in key for target in input_list)]
```

Ofcourse, it can be parallelized by having multiple threads use an item from input_list to search in the key_list. But it would be better if you share some usecase with an example to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Sandeep,
the list comprehension with "any" helped, yet again I would like to parallelize the creation of the full_path_list.
I will add an example of both lists in the description above.